# android--- can an app use custom view or any other way to make a special background?

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I am planning to write a word game and want to have a menu with  special background. Does it work?
Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: What is a "special background"?

Comment: Could you please explain more about your problem along with some code that you have tried?